# http redirecting to a defferent site

Tags: nginx, https, nginx-config

I have 3 different sites on one server and they are on port 80,81 and 82. When I go to https://port80.site.com it takes me to the site and http://port80.site.com redirect to https. With https://port81.site.com and https://port82.site.com they take me to the correct site, but when I use http on port 81/82 they just re-direct to https://port80.site.com.
So I want http://port81.site.com to re-direct to https://port81.site.com, rather than the site on port 80. On my domain my records are A port80 IP, for all 3 sites.
Im using nginx and this is my config:

```
    server {
    listen 80 or 81 or 82;
    server_name subdomain.site.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name subdomain.site.com;

    root /var/www/site;
    index index.php;

    client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    sendfile off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.site.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.site.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header Referrer-Policy same-origin;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100M";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I would guess I need to add a record to my domain, but im not really sure, im using clouflare if that makes a difference, but im not using the proxy.
Thanks.

Comment: You could try: `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` which should stop the domain name changing.

Answer (score 0):

I got it work now by doing 2 things the first what was said but doing `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` and also by making an srv record for each domain. I also had to restart the server because the `systemctl restart nginx` and `service nginx restart` didn't work.